# Error "30203 identifier expected error" when trying to compile script with online compiler

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get this script to run as a scheduled task on windows, checking with an online compiler, the message VBNC30203 identifier error was highlighted, I have looked this message up but do not have the skills to implement the fix, any help is appreciated.

The source of the script is:

http://www.642weather.com/weather/wxblog/php-scripts/scheduled-http-request-windows-task-scheduler/

I have simply entered my URL/file name in the script.

Here is my VBS code:

```
Call LogEntry()

Sub LogEntry()

'Force the script to finish on an error.
On Error Resume Next

'Declare variables
Dim objRequest
Dim URL

'The URL link.
URL = "http://www.chatteris.biz/forecast-compare-include.php?log&config=am"

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

'Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

'Send the HTML Request
objRequest.Send

'Set the object to nothing
Set objRequest = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "online compiler"?

Comment: If you save that a a .vbs file and run it, it will work as expected as its syntactically correct. VBNC30203 looks like a Mono *VB.Net* error which is nothing to do with *VBA* / *VBScript*

Comment: Alex, My error, I edited this in Notpad++ with the save option of vb/vbs, I should have tried the extension vbs rather than only vb, you are absolutely correct that the file runs now I have tried it with vbs.  Thanks you so much I know its only a small script but it has made a big difference to me you helping to get it working.  Have a great new year regards to all, Ian

Answer (score 4):

Usually in online compilers (such as tutorialspoint online compiler)
You should write your code within the Module VBModule scope and Sub Main() is needed.

Write your code like this:

```
Module VBModule

  Sub Main()
      ' Your code goes here
  End Sub

  ' Your functions / subs goes here

End Module
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        End Sub
    Public Function VAT(ByVal pCost As Double, Optional cRate As Double = 20) 
    cRate = (cRate + 100) / 100 
    Return pCost * cRate 
    End Function
    console.ReadLine()
End Module
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks